# How to use IMDSv2 from AWS Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

If an instance is configured for **IMDSv2** then after upgrading AWS-CLI we are able to connect to IMDSv2 , but we can not connect to it from java code.

Also, we could not find any documentation regarding whether we need any specific version of AWS java SDK to support IMDSv2, OR is it supported implicitly, OR is it not supported from JAVA SDK yet.

One more point is , how to ask default provider chain to use IMDSv2 while trying to load credentials.

Please let me know

Comment: I'm seeing this also - Did you find any info on it?

Comment: Du you use the 1.11.x or 2.x version?

Answer (score 3):

Support for IMDSv2 was added in:

- `1.11.678` of aws-java-sdk (commit `06a2180e`)
- `2.10.20` of aws-java-sdk-v2 (commit `53451414`)

I believe the default chain for both versions of the SDK will attempt IMDSv2, but have not verified that.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I have verified and it is working with version > 1.11.678. I have tried with two versions 1.16.678 and 1.12.159.